# Numpy divide by zero. Why?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import pygame
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fx = np.zeros([11])
fy = np.zeros([11])
x = np.zeros([11])
y = np.zeros([11])
x[0] = 11
y[0] = 1
sigma = 1.01
e = 1.1
dt = 0.1
def LJ(x,y):
    for i in range(1,10):
        for j in range(1,10):
            rx = (x[i]-x[j])
            ry = (y[i]-y[j])
            fx[i] = 24*e*(((2/rx)*sigma/rx**12)-((1/rx)*sigma/rx**6))
            fy[i] = 24*e*(((2/ry)*sigma/ry**12)-((1/ry)*sigma/ry**6))
    print fx, fy
```

Why am I still getting errors 
`RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars`
and

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

The result I am getting is

```
[  0.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan   0.] [  0.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan   0.]
```

I tried to modify starting x and y but that gave no effect.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your x and y arrays are zero but in the first entry. If your for loop iterates over the second, thirds .. entry `x[i]-x[j]` is zero, so `rx` is zero so you can't divide `2/rx`.

Comment: first entry is initial condition. I want to calculate force between two particles.

Comment: What formula do you try to implement? Why do you particles have 11 dimensions?

Comment: 11 is number of particles. I try to implement Lennard Jones force.

Comment: 10 of your particles are at the same location (at (0,0)), and for that case the formula breaks down and "infinity" or "nan" is the only reasonable result. Or is the 0 the result that is bothering you?

Comment: I do not want same location for all particles. How can I change that?

Comment: `x[i]` is probably the x coordinate of the i-th particle? And you want the force of every particle to every other particle? (Or did Jake's answer already solved your problem?)

Comment: I would strongly recommend reviewing the physics of conservative force fields and especially of the central force fields among them. Details in my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code:

```
def LJ(x,y):
    for i in range(1,10):
        for j in range(1,10):
            ...
```

If `i == j`, you are comparing a particle to itself. Try skipping that iteration of the for-loops like so:

```
def LJ(x,y):
    for i in range(1,10):
        for j in range(1,10):
            if i == j:
                continue
            rx = (x[i]-x[j])
            ry = (y[i]-y[j])
            fx[i] = 24*e*(((2/rx)*sigma/rx**12)-((1/rx)*sigma/rx**6))
            fy[i] = 24*e*(((2/ry)*sigma/ry**12)-((1/ry)*sigma/ry**6))
```

Also, you will need to put in actual values for the x and y lists, as they are all currently 0's. Two particles at exactly the same location exert an infinite amount of force according to that equation, so the divide by 0 is accurate in that scenario.

Comment: Note that this does only calculate the force between the i-th and the last particle.

Comment: And it does not really compute this force. The true force is radially symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

You should stay with the physics. The potential function is, reconstructing from your force formula,

```
LJ(r) = 4*e*(  (sigma/r)**12 - (sigma/r)**6 )
```

The force corresponding to the potential is, for any potential,

```
F = - LJ'(r)*(rx/r, ry/r)
```

Thus the procedure to compute the combined interaction forces should look like

```
def LJ(x,y):
    for i in range(x.size):
        for j in range(x.size):
            rx = (x[i]-x[j])
            ry = (y[i]-y[j])

            r = sqrt(rx*rx+ry*ry+1e-12)
            f = 24*e/r*( 2*(sigma/r)**12 - (sigma/r)**6 )

            fx[i] += f*(rx/r)
            fy[i] += f*(ry/r)
    print fx, fy
```

The condition is that at the call of the procedure the force array is initialized, either to zero or the gravitational forces only.

---

The addition of the term `eps**2` in the computation of the distance serves to avoid zero distances and thus infinite or very large values in the force computation. This epsilon `eps` should of course be small against typical distances of particles resp. the dimension of the scene, here `sigma=1.01` is a typical distance, thus `eps=1e-6` is small against it.

Comment: Can you add an explanation of the choice of the `1e-12` constant in your answer?

Comment: To avoid the problem of division by zero or forces so large that they invalidate every numerical method. This epsilon should of course be small against typical distances of particles resp. the dimension of the scene.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I thought it would make the answer better if this was explained as well. Thanks!